# Are parenthesis needed to improve performance in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-performance

Is really true that parenthesis in all conditions in postgresql improve performance?

Example:

```
SELECT field_1, field_2, ... , field_n
FROM table_x
WHERE ((field_x = a) AND (field_y = b) AND (field_z = c))
```

Comment: Whoever told you that has no idea how a query optimizer works.

Comment: Where I can an excellent query optimizer for postgresql?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you are asking with that. Do you want to use a different optimizer than the built-in? Why? Aren't you satisfied with the built-in optimizer? Why?

Comment: I don't know where it is

Comment: A query optimizer is built into the database engine. It is the piece of software that evaluates _how_ a query is executed by the database engine: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/planner-optimizer.html and http://de.slideshare.net/EnterpriseDB/how-the-postgres-query-optimizer-works and http://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-plus-edb-blog/keith-alsheimer/your-brain-postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short - no. This statement is semantically equivalent to a statement without parenthesis, and there shouldn't be any noticeable performance difference between them.